# Many documents with the same field or one array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, database, mongodb

Let's say I have a system where users can vote for items that come with an identificator.

Should I have a document for every user with an array of votes they had put in:

```
{user: A, votes: [x, y, z]}
{user: B, votes: [y, z]}
{user: C, votes: [x, z]}
```

or rather many documents for each vote:

```
{user: A, vote: x}, {user: A, vote: y}, {user: A, vote: z}
{user: B, vote: y}, {user: B, vote: z},
{user: C, vote: x}, {user: C, vote: z}
```

I feel like the second design is better but I might be wrong since I've only had experience with MySQL before.

Answer (score 1):

According to me  first design is better than that of second . Because you keep a document for a particular user . But in second case you are creating multiple document for a same user . 
Or you can create a document for particular votes i.e who all are voted for `x` or `y` .... .
Like

```
   {votes: X, users: [A,C]}
   {votes: Y, users: [A, B]}
   {votes: Z, users: [A, B,C]}
```

Comment: Any explanation why that particular design would be better? I would need to unwind the array every time i wanted to query it...